# How do I set up Chat-API correctly?

Tags: php, api, github, whatsapp

I have downloaded and installed PHP 7 and Composer.

I can use both but I don't really know what to do next.

I need PHP Protobuf and Curve25519 but I don't know how to install that.

Also, it says to do "composer require whatsapp/chat-api", but where do I have to do that when I need a .php file to write the program?